# Android service won't start

Tags: android, android-service

Ok so this is the problem. I do `context.startService(serviceIntent)`, but i don't get new log message from `OnCreate` or `OnStartCommand`.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.distorted.flashnotifier"
    android:versionCode="0"
    android:versionName="0.6" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.distorted.flashnotifier.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="FlashService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What i already tried:

- Changing service name to ".FlashService" and "com.distorted.flashnotifier.FlashService"

Activity code:

```
private Context cont;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    cont = getApplicationContext();
}

public void setNotificator() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(cont, FlashService.class);
    if(callNotificator){
        cont.startService(serviceIntent);
        Log.d("LOG", "setNotificator works");
    } else {
        cont.stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

What have i tried:

- changing all "cont" to "this"
- startService(new Intent(cont, FlashService.class));

FlashService.class:

```
package com.distorted.flashnotifier;

public class FlashService extends Service{

    public void OnCreate () {
        Log.d("LOG", "onCreate works");
    }

        public int OnStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried:

- moving Log.d to onStartCommand
- changed START_STICKY to super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

Ok so I get that setNotificator log message, but not the onCreate one.
Does anyone know how could I make this work? (Thanks for reading the whole thing).
LogCat doesn't say anything interesting.

**UPDATE:**

full Activity code:

```
package com.distorted.flashnotifier;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Home extends Activity {

    private Button timeSelectBut1;
    private Button timeSelectBut2;
    private int hour1;
    private int hour2;
    private int minute1;
    private int minute2;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID1 = 1;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID2 = 2;
    private Switch callSwitch;
    private Switch notificationSwitch;
    private boolean callNotificator;
    private boolean notifNotificator;
    private Context cont;

//IMPORTANT UNTIL timeSelectBut1.setOnClickListener

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
            cont = getApplicationContext();
        timeSelectBut1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectTimeButton1);
        timeSelectBut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID1);
            }
        });
        final Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour1 = cal1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute1 = cal1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        updateText(1);

        timeSelectBut2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectTimeButton2);
        timeSelectBut2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID2);
                }
            });
            final Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            hour2 = cal2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minute2 = cal2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            updateText(2);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        if (id == 1) {
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener1, hour1, minute1, true);
        }
        if (id == 2) {
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener2, hour2, minute2, true);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void updateText(int id) {
        if (id == 1) timeSelectBut1.setText(pad(hour1) + ":" + pad(minute1));
        if (id == 2) timeSelectBut2.setText(pad(hour2) + ":" + pad(minute2));
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener1 = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    hour1 = hourOfDay;
                    minute1 = minute;
                    updateText(1);
                }
            };
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener2 = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            hour2 = hourOfDay;
            minute2 = minute;
            updateText(2);
        }
    };

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

//IMPORTANT

    public void onCallSwitchClicked(View view) {
        boolean on = ((Switch) view).isChecked();
        if (on) {
            callNotificator = true;
            setNotificator();
            //timeSelectBut1.setText("callNotifTrue");
        } else {
            callNotificator = false;
            setNotificator();
            //timeSelectBut1.setText("callNotifFalse");
        }
    }

    public void onNotifSwitchClicked(View view) {
        boolean on = ((Switch) view).isChecked();
        if (on) {
            notifNotificator = true;
            //setNotificator();
        } else {
            notifNotificator = false;
            //setNotificator();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

//IMPORTANT

    public void setNotificator() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, FlashService.class);
        if(callNotificator){
            startService(serviceIntent);
            Log.d("LOG", "SetNotificator works");
        } else {
            stopService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So inside your onCreate method, you didn't call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); is there a reason why you didn't do that?

Comment: Activity code is actually longer. Both `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and 
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);` are there.

Comment: Manifest is the same as original, FlashService.java too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not register the service properly. Delete the line  android:permission in service
Replace your manifest by this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.distorted.flashnotifier"
android:versionCode="0"
android:versionName="0.6" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.distorted.flashnotifier.Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".FlashService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"
       >
    </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT:

After trying your code I realized that, you did not override oncreate and onstartcommand properly. In Names of the method onCreate() and onStartCommand() ,  o is not caps.. Please change it to small o and try.

Comment: Right after Manifest file.

Comment: You only changed
`<service android:name="FlashService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"
>`

to

`<service android:name=".FlashService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"
>`

As i said, I already tried that.

Comment: @kubci98   and i removed  this android:permission="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"

Comment: @kubci98  Can you paste your complete Activity code

Comment: @kubci98  I feel your callNotificator is always false

Comment: callNotificator can't be always false, because i'm getting "SetNotificator works" message via LogCat.

Comment: In manifest delete all unnecessary attributes for service.. try registering service as                                 <service android:name=".FlashService"> </service>

Comment: Well, it works now. I am also kind of ashamed because of caps O. However, thanks for your help.

Comment: @kubci98  It's my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Since you are starting your `Service` from `Activity`, the correct code is:

```
public void setNotificator() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, FlashService.class);
    if(callNotificator){
        startService(serviceIntent);
        Log.d("LOG", "setNotificator works");
    } else {
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

Moving forward, per Docs: The system calls this method when the service is first created, to perform one-time setup procedures (before it calls either `onStartCommand()` or `onBind()`). If the service is already running, this method is not called.

So I'll better put `Log` call to the `onStartCommand`

And your service is using permission, again from Docs: If a caller of `startService()`, `bindService()`, or `stopService()`, has not been granted this permission, the method will not work and the Intent object will not be delivered to the service. If this attribute is not set, the permission set by the `<application>` element's permission attribute applies to the service. If neither attribute is set, the service is not protected by a permission.